# How does one change the chromium icon automatically after updating?

Tags: icons, chromium

I use the daily ppa build of Chromium.  The daily build uses a [PNG I believe instead of an SVG](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=59825), so it looks rather horrid on my dock.

[image: Blurry Chromium Icon]

And zoomed in:

[image]

(Not too sure why the icon is getting clipped in this screenshot, I did a select area method which perhaps has made it funky.  Anyway, you get the idea!)

So after every update, I have to manually go into /usr/share/applications and manually select an SVG Chromium icon for the Chromium launcher to use.  Since Chromium uses the daily build, this is rather tedious to do following every update.

Is there a means / scripting method that can be put into place that will automatically change Chromium's icon following an update of Chromium?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Allan's](https://askubuntu.com/users/6450) answer should work, but here is another way:

1. Copy `/usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop` to your Desktop:

   `cp /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop ~/Desktop`
2. Select a custom icon.

   *Right click -> Properties -> Permissions -> Check **Allow executing file as program***.
   Now go back to the *Basic* tab and click on the icon in the upper left to select a new icon.
3. Move this launcher to `~/.local/share/applications/`:

   `cp ~/Desktop/chromium-browser.desktop ~/.local/share/applications`
4. You should now see this launcher with the icon you selected in the Application menu, so add it to your Dock.
5. That's it! This launcher won't be overwritten every time you upgrade Chromium. You may need to restart your dock for it to notice.

Comment: Strangely, this didn't work for me: when I copied chromium-browser.desktop to my desktop, it turned into a generic ".desktop" icon and wouldn't let me change it.  Anyway, I managed to successfully achieve the correct icon by copying chromium-browser.svg to /usr/share/icons and ~/.icons.  Thanks for the detailed answer though! (I probably just did something wrong I suppose)

Comment: @Magic The `Icon` field of the `.desktop` file is still being changed even if it doesn't seem like it. But that is confusing, so see my updated answer.

Comment: Yes I think DoR's answer is a lot better than mine and usually there is more than One way to fry a fish when it comes to Ubuntu. One of the reasons I like it. And the more options you have the better when it comes to solving a problem. Plus I now know of 4 ways to change Icons in Ubuntu bonus!

Comment: Ah there we go!  Though by the way, I did get the following error when attempting to copy: $ cp ~/Desktop/chromium-browser.desktop ~/local/share/applications
cp: cannot create regular file `/home/peter/local/share/applications': No such file or directory
but manually copying worked!  Thanks both of you!  Edit Number 2: Unfortunately now there is a working launcher of Chromium, but it launches a separate Chromium icon (fuzzy)!  Clearly this is an issue with Docky I suppose...

Comment: @Magic My bad, there was a missing `.` in that command. When you manually copied the launcher, did you copy it to ~/.local/share...(with the `.`)
or ~/local/share... (no `.`)?

Comment: I copied it to ~/.local/share.  The launcher looks fine, it's just unfortunate that Docky thinks that it needs to create a new icon for Chromium that is the launched Chromium :(

Comment: @Magic So the launcher in Docky is using the icon you set? Or not?

Comment: It is indeed using the icon I set.  However it launches a separate application (it creates a new Chromium application next to the launcher upon opening Chromium)

Comment: @Magic The only way it seems to get around that is to temporarily rename `/usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop` to something else and then add the launcher.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is possibly what you are looking for

[HOWTO: Custom Icon Themes](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=251567)

I'm fairly sure that per user icons eg Icon's in your .icon folder super-seed the Icons that are provided elsewhere but I could be wrong. Its worth a shot.